# DNN instance with multiple application ids

Tags: dotnetnuke

This might be too specific of a problem - but any ideas are appreciated

I have a DNN 3.2.2 instance that is sort of broken right now - the main item that shows up is the User Admin screen will not appear it has a application error.

Looking in the Database there are two application IDs in aspnet_Applications and some uses use one and some users use the other

I have tried setting all the users in aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership to one or the other application id to see if this fixes the error but this does not fix the problem

Anyone have some ideas on a fix for this ??

Comment: Sounds to me like something else is going on.  Did someone try and merge two DNN sites then call you to fix it?  Are ALL of the binaries and other files really 3.2.2 or is it mixed up?  Have you thought about doing a clean 3.2.2 install, then just migrating the data?

Comment: All the files are 3.2.2 - that was one of my first thoughts too - was replace the 3.2.2 files and make sue someoen didnt break them

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you have 1 application, but the membership db thinks there is 2?  That sounds pretty messed up, the best solution would probably be to write an SQL script that migrates all users under 1 app to the other.

In terms of your quick fix, I didn't see you mention aspnet_Roles, which will also contain the ApplicationId.  Not changing that table too could explain why it didn't work. i.e. You changed the app for a user, but not that user's roles.

Comment: yeah moved the roles over - not sure on this - probably just rebuild the site - SIGH!

Answer (score 0):

Open up your web.config and look for the *AspNetSqlMembershipProvider* node and look for the *applicationName* attribute. By default, this should be set to "DotNetNuke".

Now open up your database, and look in the *AspNet_Applications* table and see which *ApplicationId* maps to "DotNetNuke" (or whatever you have in your web.config).

Now, in theory, all your portal users should be mapped to that *ApplicationId*.
Now open look at the *AspNet_Membership* and *AspNet_Users* tables and ensure that the *ApplicationId* matches the *ApplicationId* that this DotNetNuke instance is mapped to.

I know you know this, but I'll say it, back your database before changing this - so you can track your steps back.

Also, I am not entirely sure this is your problem, but this might be a good step in the right direction.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Comment: Antonio - yeah - tried that no go - sorry - doing this all in test environment from coppies so i have done it like ten different times - great thing is i can restore site in about 1 minute